# $y'+y=x^2y^2$ ? linear differential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can we solve the following:

$$y'+y=x^2y^2$$

**My attempt**: [image]

Comment: Note that $$\int-x^2e^{-x}\, dx$$ can be solved using integration by parts.

Comment: Please use mathjax to write the formulas for all relevant intermediate steps up to the point where you get no further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We start with
\begin{align}
y'+y&=x^2y^2\\
\frac {y'}{y^2}+\frac{1}{y}&=x^2
\end{align}
Let $$z=\frac 1y$$
then you have
$$z'=-\frac{y'}{y^2}$$

So
$$-z'+z=x^2$$
The integrating factor is
$$e^{-\int dx}=e^{-x}$$
So
$$(e^{-x}z)'=-x^2e^{-x}$$
Using integration by parts,
\begin{align}
e^{-x}z&=\int{-x^2e^{-x}} \ dx\\
&=x^2e^{-x}-2\int xe^{-x} \ dx\\
&=x^2e^{-x}-2\left(-xe^{-x}-\int -e^{-x} \ dx \right) \ dx\\
&=x^2e^{-x}+2xe^{-x}+2e^{-x}+C\\
z&=x^2+2x+2+Ce^x
\end{align}
Hence,
$$y=\frac{1}{x^2+2x+2+Ce^{x}}$$

Answer (score 4):

This is a Bernoulli equation. Divide by $y^2$ and set $u=\dfrac1y$, $u'=-\dfrac{y'}{y^2}$ to get a linear DE.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Bernoulli differential equation. We start off by removing $y$ term from the right. According to the snapshot posted, it seems like you're on the right track.

$$\begin{align}\dfrac1{y^2}y'+\dfrac1y&=x^2\end{align}$$
Let $v=\dfrac1y\implies\dfrac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}=-\dfrac1{y^2}y'$

$$\begin{align}-\dfrac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}+v&=x^2\\\dfrac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}-v&=-x^2\qquad(\text{Linear DE})\end{align}$$

Integrating factor $=e^{\int -1\,\mathrm dx}=e^{-x}$

Multiplying throughout with the integrating factor, the equation will take the form of...

$$\begin{align}\int\mathrm d[ve^{-x}]&=\int-x^2e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx\\ve^{-x}&=\int-x^2e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx\end{align}$$

Implying tabular integration for the right side...
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}u&\pm&\mathrm dv\\\hline -x^2&\text{null}&e^{-x}\\-2x&+&-e^{-x}\\-2&-&e^{-x}\\0&+&-e^{-x}\end{array}$$
Now, cross multiplying to obtain the result....

$$\begin{align}ve^{-x}&=x^2e^{-x}+2xe^{-x}+2e^{-x}+C\\v&=x^2+2x+2+Ce^x\\y&=\boxed{\dfrac1{x^2+2x+2+Ce^x}}\end{align}$$